# Extract the pixels around the point

Tags: google-earth-engine

In order to avoid the users' memory limited, I want to extract the 3-by-3 pixel around the sample point,like:

[image]

the black rectangle is the region that I want to retain.I've tried to make a buffer around the point,then make a mask and extract the pixel, but it doesn't work. because the piont is not exactly in the center of the pixel.once I mask them,it turns a mixture pixel back, like:
[image]

here's the code that I've tried:

```
var SP = /* color: #d63000 */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.85406791058324, 51.77391345149662]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.708842385680896, 51.72672790533219]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.99963675823949, 51.76180294694399]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "2"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.911402810485583, 51.71290298723783]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "3"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.918612588317615, 51.70141445606971]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "4"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([10.956378091247302, 51.70907380102543]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "5"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([11.008563149841052, 51.724388600937246]),
            {
              "class": 1,
              "system:index": "6"
            })]),
    l82 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA"),
    geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[10.853573489088495, 51.77362011926037],
          [10.854877042669733, 51.77359024517469],
          [10.854919958013971, 51.77440347711523],
          [10.853611040014703, 51.77443003138049]]]);
var image = l82.filterBounds(SP).filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-02-01').first();
//here is my thought,but it didn't work
var buffer = SP.map(function(i){return i.buffer(45).bounds()});
var mask = buffer.reduceToImage(['class'],ee.Reducer.first());
var ROI = image.updateMask(mask);
Map.centerObject(geometry,18);
Map.addLayer(ROI,{},"ROI");
Map.addLayer(geometry,{},"RegionThatIwantToRemain");
```

and[here's the link of my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c05425de7c61ef158be6a54e17881b80)

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (a sample of code that reproduces your current situation). It will be much easier for people to help if they have a starting point.

Comment: thanks for your advice , and I've put the link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For this you may want to try the [coveringGrid](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-coveringgrid) method with the image’s projection. Building off of your original script, here's a [solution](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe95b7284d2c1abfe8b9c5b18cb60a5a) that calls coveringGrid on the image’s geometry. We then filter it to get a buffer around the point. With regards to the size of the buffer, in order to get exactly 30m (1 pixel), you can use the scale of the image. I added a few lines to get, print, and use the scale to do so.

```
var nominal_scale = image.select("B1").projection().nominalScale()
print(nominal_scale)
var buffer = SP.map(function(i){return i.buffer(nominal_scale).bounds()});
...
var grid = image.geometry().coveringGrid(image.select("B1").projection());
var filtered = grid.filterBounds(buffer)
```